# Emu8086 pusha popa

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I'm looking for an easy way of pusha popa in assembly program. I want to use emu8086 to find bugs in my programs so  .286 is not allowed.
I tried:

```
push_a proc
push ax
push cx
push dx
push bx
push sp
push bp
push si
push di
push_a endp

pop_a proc
pop di
pop si
pop bp
pop sp
pop bx
pop dx
pop cx
pop ax
pop_a endp
```

But it doesn't work, thus when we "call push_a" we push to a stack an address where we are now.
Is there another easy, simple way? I don't want to write eight push and eight pop every time.

Comment: Does emu8086 support macros?

Comment: http://www.coval.net/teach/emu8086/helpfiles/asm_tutorial_10.html

Comment: "If you declared a macro and never used it in your code, compiler will simply ignore it. emu8086.inc is a good example of how macros can be used, this file contains several macros to make coding easier for you."

Comment: It seems that yes it supports macro.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One could implement the procedures as macros

```
pusha MACRO
   push ax
   push cx
   push dx
   push bx
   push sp
   push bp
   push si
   push di
pusha ENDM

popa MACRO
   pop di
   pop si
   pop bp
   pop sp
   pop bx
   pop dx
   pop cx
   pop ax
popa ENDM
```

but this is not the architectural behaviour of `pusha`/`popa` and it is broken code on a real 8086.

### The real semantic of `pusha`

The `push sp` in `pusha` should push the state of the stack pointer *at the start* of the `pusha` macro.

> Temp ← (SP);
>   Push(AX);
>   Push(CX);
>   Push(DX);
>   Push(BX);
>   Push(Temp);
>   Push(BP);
>   Push(SI);
>   Push(DI);
>
> <sup>Intel pseudo-code for `pusha` - Intel Manual 2B</sup>

**Using a scratch memory location**

You can do something similar if you have a scratch memory location:

```
pusha MACRO
   mov WORD PTR [pusha_scratch], sp
   push ax
   push cx
   push dx
   push bx
   push WORD PTR [pusha_scratch]
   push bp
   push si
   push di 
pusha ENDM
```

Making sure that the `pusha_scratch` is accessible through `DS` under any context can be quite of an endeavour.
Not accounting for a separate definition of `pusha_scratch`.

**Using a position independent, in-place, version**

Alternatively one could account for the modified value of `sp` with something that is position independent and operates in-place.
If I did my math correctly - double check it - this code should do the trick

```
pusha MACRO
   push ax
   push cx
   push dx
   push bx

   push bp                  ;Top of stack = BP
   mov bp, sp               ;BP points to TOS
   lea bp, [bp+0ah]         ;BP is equal to the starting value of SP
   xchg bp, [bp-0ah]        ;BP = Original BP, [SP] = Starting value of BP

   push bp
   push si
   push di
pusha ENDM
```

<sup>Many thanks to [Fifoernik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971287/emu8086-pusha-popa/42973658?noredirect=1#comment73310526_42973658) for correcting the broken code by noting the inverted math and preventing the altering of the EFLAGS register.</sup>

The nice thing about the snippet above is that it avoids using `push sp` entirely as it is a bit problematic when it comes to backward compatibility.

### The problem of `push sp`

On a real 8086 the instruction `push sp` behaves differently:

> The P6 family, Pentium, Intel486, Intel386, and Intel 286 processors push a different value on the stack for a `PUSH SP` instruction than the 8086 processor.
>   The 32-bit processors push the value of the SP register before it is decremented as part of the push operation;
>   **the 8086 processor pushes the value of the SP register after it is decremented**.
>
> <sup>Intel compatibility section - Intel Manual 3 - 22.17</sup>

I don't know how accurate emu8086 is as an emulator of the 8086 but I would avoid `push sp`.

### The semantic of `popa`

The peculiar way `pusha` is implemented calls for a peculiar implementation of `popa`.
On a real 8086 a naive list of `pop`s breaks as soon as `pop sp` is executed.

Indeed the CPU exploits the fact that you can't really modify `sp` even after a `pusha` - otherwise there would be no way to get those values back - and notices that after all the `pop`s the original value is implicitly restored.

> DI ← Pop();
>   SI ← Pop();
>   BP ← Pop();
>   Increment ESP by 2; (* Skip next 2 bytes of stack *)
>   BX ← Pop();
>   DX ← Pop();
>   CX ← Pop();
>   AX ← Pop();
>
> <sup>Intel pseudo-code for `popa` - Intel Manual 2B</sup>

So a more correct implementation of `popa` is

```
popa MACRO
   pop di
   pop si
   pop bp
   add sp, 02h         ;Beware, this affects EFLAGS
   pop bx
   pop dx
   pop cx
   pop ax
popa ENDM
```

**Note** that you must avoid `pop sp` in a real 8086 as a `push sp` followed by a `pop sp` is not idempotent, for

> The `POP ESP` instruction increments the stack pointer (ESP) before data at the old top of stack is written into the
>   destination.
>
> <sup>Intel description for `pop` - Intel Manual 2B</sup>

Finally, one would expect `pusha`/`popa` to be atomic with respect to interrupts, so a `cli`/`sti` pair is needed around the macro bodies.

---

If you use `pusha`/`popa` just as a shorthand for saving all the registers, then all the hassle can be skipped and a sufficient implementation is

```
 push_all MACRO
   push ax
   push cx
   push dx
   push bx
   ;NOTE: Missing SP
   push bp
   push si
   push di
push_all ENDM

pop_all MACRO
   pop di
   pop si
   pop bp
   ;NOTE: Missing SP
   pop bx
   pop dx
   pop cx
   pop ax
pop_all ENDM
```

Comment: This is a great answer!

Comment: "If I did my math correctly - double check it - this code should do the trick" Sadly this is wrong. The stack grows downward and so the math must go the other way.    `sub bp, 0ah` `xchg bp, [bp+0ah]`  >>>    __`add bp, 0ah` `xchg bp, [bp-0ah]`__

Comment: What you neglect totally with this replacement code is the fact that `pusha`/`popa` don't alter the `EFLAGS`. The `add bp, 10` would better become __`lea bp, [bp+10]`__

Comment: @Fifoernik You are right! Thank you very much for your feedback! That snippet was totally broken indeed.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for an easy way of pusha popa in assembly program.

and

> I don't want to write eight push and eight pop every time.

This is exactly what you will be doing when you use the proposed MACRO solution! Each time you use the name of the macro, the entire block of code that it represents is substituted. This truly will be a waste of space.

Although the answer by @MargaretBloom is excellent in explaining all the problems with `push sp` and `pop sp`, it doesn't give you the easiest solution. Moreover in the context of preserving and restoring all the general purpose registers, pushing and popping the stackpointer is a silly operation. Even the manufacturer (Intel) knows this and cleverly bypasses the pushed `SP` value when performing `popa`. The `SP` register is pushed by `pusha` only because it simplifies the hardware design.

The best solution then that fulfills the requirements temporarily removes the return address from `call push_a` / `call pop_a` before pushing / popping the 7 useful GPRs. Directly before executing `ret` the return address is put back on the stack. Voilà.

```
push_a proc
    pop word ptr [TEMP]
    push ax
    push cx
    push dx
    push bx
    push bp
    push si
    push di
    push word ptr [TEMP]
push_a endp

pop_a proc
    pop word ptr [TEMP]
    pop di
    pop si
    pop bp
    pop bx
    pop dx
    pop cx
    pop ax
    push word ptr [TEMP]
pop_a endp
```

This solution also does not alter any of the flags for its operation. Was observed by @Fifoernik.
Here's an idea: Why not preserve the FLAGS as an eighth register?

One final note. To make this code really robust you could put this TEMP variable in the code segment of your program and address it with an explicite `CS:` override prefix. Your `DS` segment register might not always be in the correct place when you need to use your new *push_a* / *pop_a* calls. Your `CS` register inherently will be correct. If it weren't, the `call` would not even function.

Answer (score -1):

```
pushuj    MACRO  
    push ax
    push cx
    push dx
    push bx
    push sp
    push bp
    push si
    push di

ENDM
```

and when i want to call it i write:

```
pushuj
```

I it good?